# How to read log files and filter based on control characters using Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to PySpark and want to read a log file with many lines of binary code separated by the newline character. I need to filter the file using:

1. the length of the binary line greater than 1
2. the binary line starts with `\x00`

Here is an example line from one of the input files:

`b'\x18\xb5\x1fM\x00\x02\x00\x^C\x05\x00\x00\x96\x93\x80@2\xf6\x1f2\x01\n'`

I encounter an error in checking the 0 positions of each line for `\x00`. The error is:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from b#2:
> need struct type but got string;

Here is my code.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import length
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, size
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring_index, substring
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
import numpy as np

sc = SparkContext( 'local', 'test')
spark=SparkSession(sc)

textFile = sc.textFile("/test_log.mi2log")
results=textFile.collect()


rdd1 = sc.parallelize(results)
row_rdd = rdd1.map(lambda x: Row(x))
df=spark.createDataFrame(row_rdd,['b'])
df=df.filter(length(df.b)>1)
df=df.filter(df.b[0]==b'\x00')
```

For the last filter command, I want to read the binary data into the RDD or a dataframe. Thanks!

Comment: It is confusing that you are mentioning binary data, along with lines and newline characters, which are elements of text data. Can you add an example of your data to help contributors? (cut down lines if they are long).

Comment: Sure, like this, this is the line reader using Python readline() b'\x18\xb5\x1fM\x00\x02\x00\x^C\x05\x00\x00\x96\x93\x80@2\xf6\x1f2\x01\n'

Comment: Ok, I've edited the question and can provide an answer if gets re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

You have a text log file with control characters, so you can read it as a text file and filter on the null control character:

```
textFile = sc.textFile("/test_log.mi2log")
filtered_rdd = textFile.filter(lambda line: len(line) > 1 and line[0] == '\x00')
print(filtered_rdd.collect())
```

Comment: Did you have any success with this @MarccccH ?